# How can I register an OCX file in Python

Tags: python, dll, ocx, rundll32

How can I register a OCX file (call rundll32) in Python?

I tried

```
from ctypes import windll
dll = windll[r'C:\Path\To\Some.DLL']
result = dll.DllRegisterServer( )
result = dll.DllUnregisterServer( )
```

but it gives me errors.